# How to get custom customer address attribute in checkout billing section?

Tags: attributes, magento-1, custom, customer-attribute

I try this `$this->getAddress()->getNickName()` but not working, 
It working in edit page.

In checkout billing page I got validation class in text field.

```
$this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('nick_name');
```

Comment: in which attribute set(table eav_entity_attribute) you add the nicname attribute?

Comment: yes , i try add Nick name in billing & shipping section, it added in eav_attribute

Comment: what is the attribute_set_id? and do you add customer_form_attribute form_code value as "checkout_register"

Comment: entity_type_id is 2 in  eav_attribute  table

Comment: What is the attribute_code in eav_attribute table?

Comment: attribute_code in eav_attribute table is nick_name

Comment: @ReniRajNR  where did you try this code ? which file you are referencing here ?

Comment: app/design/frontend/rwd/********/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Check the attribute set in the table **eav_entity_attribute** column **attribute_set_id**.

and check the attribute_id inserted in the **customer_form_attribute** table under column **form_code**.

**Update**
 Try this in your billing.phtml

```
<input type="text" name="billing[nick_name]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getNickName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Nick Name#') ?>" id="billing:nick_name" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

Comment: I checked , Its added

Comment: try the update, this is the way i did for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map in the fieldset section of your config.xml file or it will not be saved after order completition. It is a common pitfall.

Have a look here, there is a complete example: 
http://magentoabid.blogspot.it/2012/08/how-to-add-custom-field-in-one-page.html

Answer (score -1):

**Please follow step by step below link**

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/